# Strategies/Schema for Unique Constraint depending on Grandparent ID

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema

I'm using Rails 4 with Postgres (newest version). Wondering about design theory and best practice.

Here is my current schema:

```
create table Company
(
  id int not null primary key
)

create table Project 
(
  id int not null primary key,
  company_id int not null references Company
)

create table Orders
(
  id int not null,
  project_id int not null references Project, 
  po_number int
)
```

1) My question is how to create a unique constraint on Orders po_number scoped to a Company. I can't think of a way at the database level, so is that suggesting that my schema is designed poorly?

2) Would it be wise to add company_id to Orders? Are there negatives to doing this?

Comment: Server version?

Comment: @Akina sorry, I'm using Postgres, figure the newest version.

Comment: @Akina would the theory behind this question not be database agnostic for the most part?

Comment: You are right, given the current structure, you can't define a unique constraint on the orders table like that. For that you would have to include the `company_id` into the orders table.

Comment: I think you may try the next way. Create a function `get_order_id(IN project_id)` which calculates `company.id` for a record in `Orders` table based on given `project_id` value, and define it as immutable. Create calculated column which concatenates `po_number` field and `get_order_id(project_id)` using a space as a delimiter. Create unique index by this calculated field.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - thank you, would you be able to answer each of my questions more specifically? I'm especially interested about best practices and why or why not I should do something.

Comment: @Akina would this be more desirable than simply adding company_id to orders? For what reasons?

Comment: Potential inconsistency. One company for order directly but another via project.